# Angular getCurrentNavigation().extras

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sending data along with the route from my component and I want to retrieve it in the other component's constructor:

**Sending data:**

```
this.router.navigate(['/coaches/list'], {
          state: { updateMessage: this.processMessage },
          replaceUrl: true
        });
```

**Retrieving data in the constructor:**

```
if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.state != null) {
  this.successMessage = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the first time the extras.state is undefined without any data. It is only when I close the dialog button in the other component that this variable will be filled.

Please tell me how can I resolve the issue as I am getting **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null** in the initial loading.

Comment: Asked and answered within 2 minutes, by yourself! Looks like this post could get flag my friend.

Comment: How do you inject router in constructor? Are you sure you did like this : constructor(private router: Router){} .... By the way, @Ronnie I think he didn't answer this, yet he wanted to add something to the current problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @FatihErsoy, that makes sense.

Comment: @Ahmad, I would suggest you go ahead and edit the OP with the additional details, so its not confusing for the future readers. Tx

Comment: Hi everyone: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by checking, if the getCurrentNavigation is null:

```
    constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public commonService: CommonService
  ) {
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation() != null) {
      this.successMessage = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access state by this:

```
history.state.updateMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this to be one line of code, which will make your message equal `null` if `getCurrentNavigation()` will be non-truthy:

```
this.successMessage = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
```

Or this, if you would like to specify empty value:

```
this.successMessage = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state ?? 'YOUR VALUE';
```